# Background noise on a amplifier even when no audio is playing

Tags: amplifier, audio, texas-instruments

In order to try to use a high quality headphones-amp [TI TPA6111A2](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa6111a2.pdf), I'm connecting the input to 0V (i.e. no audio input) **to first see if I get a clean very-low-noise silence sound in the case no audio is flowing.**

According to the datasheet linked before, it gives something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fczWQw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I payed attention to "Typical Application Circuit" (page 1) and page 14, 15, 16 for the choices of the resistors / capacitors.

Still, I get an audio buzz. It is clearly too much, as the TPA6111 is said to be really better than I have according to its specs.

**How to debug such a buzz, even when no audio is flowing?**

Comment: Can you show your layout?

Comment: @replete it's on a breadboard for now

Comment: Ouch. It's still worth showing a photo of the breadboard construction and double-checking the quality of all connections.

Comment: Unless your power is from batteries, this buzz is likely 120Hz ripple.

Comment: Check the ripple on your power rails and check your inputs for sanity. The rails on the RPi are not quiet, by any means, and probably have lots of digital gunk from the loads on the RPi as well as some of the gunk from the 5V supplying it. In short, use audio rails for audio circuits and keep them electrically distant from digital rails.

Answer (score 2):

A starting point to troubleshoot an apparent 'BUZZ' with a shorted input would be to power your audio widget separately with a low-noise supply (like a linear bench lab supply).

If you don't have a supply handy, you can excessively filter the incoming power rail. The no-load but active quiescent current of the TPA6111A2 is 3 mA. So you can easily add a series resistor of 100 ohms and afford drop 300 mV. Add additional bypass capacitors to lower the low-pass filter even further.

Layout is also critical for performance, tie the ground leg of Ci as close to the op-amp ground pin as possible.

Comment: Thanks @sstobbe. During my prototyping phase, can I use electrolytic caps for all caps present in this schematic (from 0.1u to 100u)? I might buy a kit [like this](https://www.amazon.fr/OULII-Valeurs-Condensateurs-%C3%A9lectrolytiques-Assortiment/dp/B01JU58FG6/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1496133234&sr=1-1&keywords=assortiment+condensateurs). Or do some of the caps here **absolutely need** to be ceramic or tentalum or anything else?

Comment: Everything except for the 100 nF caps are perfectly fine as electrolytics. It would most likely work with 100nF electrolytics but 100nF ceramics are used everywhere so if you do buy them you will find many uses in the future.

Comment: If you don't have a linear bench supply, use either three  AA batteries in series or a single cell lithium-ion battery.  Batteries (particularly ones with low ESR/high current capacity) are very very low noise.  Also, the 100nF caps should be very low ESR and mounted as close to the chip as possible.  The cheapest solution is ceramic, but some electrolytics might work.